# SSIS Double Backslash is causing connection issues

Tags: ssis, double, backslash

I'm currently using an Execute SQL Task to pull in dynamic information to build my connection string for each of my databases.  From there I'm passing them to a Foreach Loop.  At this point I'm building my connection string using an expression:

"Data Source="+ @[User::DatabaseServer]+ "\\"+@[User::Instance]+";User ID="+@[User::UserName]+ ";Password="+ @[User::Password] +";Initial Catalog=Defaul;Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;"

My issue is the following, when my connection string is built with a double backslash.

Data Source=DatabaseServer\\InstanceName;User ID=UserName;Password=Password;Initial Catalog=Default;Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;

Does anyone know how to prevent the double backslash from occurring?  I've tried to use the escape characters but I have had 0 success.

Comment: When I use that same expression in SSIS 2012 the backslash is successfully escaped, what's the issue exactly>

Comment: I'm currently using 2008.  So in my expression I have to use a double backslash so that it will parse correctly.  However, when it builds my connection string it includes both backslashes.

Comment: I even when so far to updated my data in my table so that the connection string would reside there and it still added a second backslash.

Comment: How do you observe this double backslash? All of that looks correct to me. If you use a script task to messagebox/fireinformation event, does it show the doubled slash? You might see one if you visually inspect values in the debugger but that's an artifact of the inspector and not an actual doubling of the slashes. In your expression, I see that you are hard coding your initial catalog to `Defaul` in the expression but the resolved connection string indicates `Default`.

Comment: hi tim did you tried the soln I suggested ?

Answer (score 0):

```
i found a work around of the issue  :


what I have done is :

I have taken the first parameter for connction string like : "anystaring
and the second parameter for the db is :  newdb"

so now check the screenshot I have given the URL(not able to upload the image sorry):
```

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2v3oj6x&s=8#.VHQ8aSjrbcs