# SSIS ConnectionString Escape Character is causing connection failure

Tags: ssis, connection-string

I'm have a SSIS connection string that includes an escape character which is preventing the connection string from working.  Does anyone know how to prevent the escape character from being applied?

Here is an example of my database connection: DatabaseServer\DInstanceName

Comment: Is this the same issue on your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26538143/ssis-double-backslash-is-causing-connection-issues)?

Answer (score 0):

If you're building connection string dynamically from `variables` or even if you don't, you can use  `Properties-> Expressions-> Connection string expression` where you can test the resulting output of the expression. And use `\` to escape any character.

Better approach would be to use `SSIS XML Configuration` so you don't need to edit your package everytime you need to make some changes in connection string.

Answer (score 0):

the escaping will be "\" it will give you \ but for your connection string I alredy give a solution on you other ques . here also I am pasting the same thing. plz check it :)

I have taken the first parameter for connction string like : **"anystaring**
and the second parameter for the db is :  **newdb"**

so now check the screenshot I have given the URL(not able to upload the image sorry):

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2v3oj6x&s=8#.VHQ8aSjrbcs